# Multiple instanceof checks

Tags: php, instanceof

Is there a shorter way of checking if a object is part of a certain set of classes?

Using `instanceof` makes the `if` statement too long:

```php
if($obj instanceof \Class1 || $obj instanceof \Class2 || $obj instanceof \Class3)
```

And this doesn't work:

```php
instance of \Class1 || \Class2 || \Class3
```

It assumes that `Class2` is constant.

Comment: Do these classes have something in common? Perhaps they are all implementing the same interface, and you can check if your `$obj` implements that interface instead?

Comment: Too localized? I found this 5 years later and it's still useful.

Comment: You can use 
If (is_a( $obj, 'Class1\\ Class2\\ Class3'))

Answer (score 10):

> makes the IF statement too long
>
> [...]
>
> Is there a shorter way

Sure.

Simply **create a function**:

```
function isOfValidClass($obj)
{
    $classNames = array('Class1', 'Class2');
    foreach ($classNames as $className) {
        if (is_a($obj, $className)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you can use that in your code and not have to worry about your if statement "taking up too much room" (not that you should ever consider that an issue; statements should be as long as they need to).

Answer (score 8):

In short: No

The longer answer: You can create workarounds, that use `get_parent_class()` recursive to fetch all parent classes and then use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array-intersect) to find out, if one or more of your class names appears there. However, it seems, that they classes should have something in common. Put this into an interface an test against this.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the shortest way is to put the Boolean expression in a external method and call it into the IF statement.